# How to disable ion-card for Ionic 3?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I want to disable ion-card using the **disabled** attribute which is listed on official documentation. I tried using it but nothing happens and i still can interact with the card.

I also tried using **[disabled]** still it doesn't disable the card.

What is the proper way to achieve this?

code:

```
<ion-card (click)="openControllerPage('ERD')" disabled='true'>
          <ion-card-content>
            <div style="text-align: center;">
              <img src="assets/imgs/executive_dashboard.png" style="height: 30px;width: 30px">
              <h2 style="color: #8d8d8d"><b>Executive<br> Dashboard</b></h2>
            </div>
          </ion-card-content>
 </ion-card>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your tag in question, you are using ionic 3, then you are also looking at wrong documentation. You should look at the [version 3 documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/)

The disable feature for card on ionic 3 didn't exist, but was introduced in ionic 4. So you need to somehow work around this, which programmatically can be done like in answer [here](http://ttps://stackoverflow.com/a/39347582/7741865). Demo for that: **[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-8vwdaw?file=pages/home/home.html)**

That is, if you want to conditionally want to disable card, you can use a boolean flag for that:

```
(click)="isDisabled ? $event.stopPropagation() : openControllerPage('ERD'); isDisabled ? false : null"
[class.isDisabled]="isDisabled"
```

otherwise just remove the click event from the card completely if it should always be disabled.

... but whatever path you choose, then you would also need to probably style the card when disabled, so that user can see that the card is in fact disabled.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I am not able to open the link that you have provided

Comment: well did an update to answer, don't know if you conditionally want to disable the card, or if always disable the card. But I guess anyway you choose, you need to do some styling of the card to indicate it is disabled, if you have other cards on same page that are enabled.

Comment: This works! i didn't get the css part. How am i suppose to change the css? what does [class.isDisabled]="isDisabled" mean?

Comment: it adds a `disabled` class to html element, based on condition `isDisabled`. Naming is just same. Then you can work with the `disabled` class in the css/scss/sass file that you have, **if** you want to somehow style the card so that the user can clearly see that the card is disabled.

Comment: I added .isDisabled
      {
        pointer-events: none;
        opacity: 0.5;
      }
in the css file but it doesn't apply this class conditionally, it applies this all the time weather isDisabled is true or false

Comment: Okay it is working fine!
Thank you for helping me out!

Answer (score 1):

## page.html

```
    <ion-card disabled="true">
    <p>Text</p>
    </ion-card>
```

//without Disable

https://prnt.sc/p9olvz

//with disable

https://prnt.sc/p9om69

see your code with/without disable properties

Comment: its working fine, my side, and also your code working fine

Comment: this is strange

Comment: why am i not getting the same result?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
<ion-card (click)="openControllerPage('ERD')" [disabled]="true">
          <ion-card-content>
            <div style="text-align: center;">
              <img src="assets/imgs/executive_dashboard.png" style="height: 30px;width: 30px">
              <h2 style="color: #8d8d8d"><b>Executive<br> Dashboard</b></h2>
            </div>
          </ion-card-content>
 </ion-card>
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the doc, `disabled="true"` should do the trick, but as a workaround you can use the `user-select: none;`

**.html**

```
<ion-card disabled="true">
  ...
</ion-card>
```

**.sccs**

```
ion-card[disabled="true"] {
  user-select: none;
}
```